# Openshift Zend Server Login - 414 request URI too large

Tags: openshift, zend-server

I am trying to login to Zend server on Openshift and I get this error

Request-URI Too Large
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at localhost Port 80

Any help?

Comment: Which zend cartridge are you using?

Comment: Cartridges - PHP 5.4 with Zend Server 6.1, MySQL 5.5 and phpMyAdmin 4.0. The application deployed is working fine but unable to access the server.